# Book about a young girl with a special necklace who time travels to England during the reign of Henry VIII

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

Can you help me find a book my daughter read in 2020?

- It was a chapter book.
- Pink cover.
- For kids of middle school age level (I think).
- About a young girl who has a special necklace and she travels to the past (England in the time of Henry VIII).
- She works in the palace and travels back and forth between past and present.
- In the present, she is a fashion blogger.
- I think her name was something along the lines of Ashley Rose??

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your question if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)

Answer (score 7):

Is this ***[The Portal](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40604799-the-portal)*** (2019) by Kathryn Lasky...? It's the first book in the *[Tangled in Time](https://www.goodreads.com/series/246431-tangled-in-time)* duology.

According to the Goodreads blurb, the protagonist is a fashion blogger named Rose who investigates a strange light in her grandmother's Tudor-style greenhouse and is transported back in time to England during the reign of King Henry VIII, where she becomes the servant of the banished Princess Elizabeth. The blurb also mentions that she discovers a locket with two mysterious images inside it.

> Life used to be great for **Rose**: full of friends, a loving mom, and a growing **fashion blog**.
>
> But when her mother dies in a car crash, Rose is sent away to live with a strange grandmother she hardly knows and forced to attend a new school where mean girls ridicule her at every turn.
>
> **The one place Rose finds refuge is in her grandmother’s Tudor-style greenhouse. But one night, she sees a strange light glowing from within it. She climbs a ladder to investigate . . . and finds herself transported back four hundred years to Hatfield Palace, where she becomes servant and confidante of the banished princess Elizabeth, daughter of King Henry VIII. Rose soon discovers something else surprising—a locket with two mysterious images inside it, both of them clues to her own past.**
>
> Could her grandmother’s greenhouse portal offer answers to the mysteries of her family . . . and their secrets? And how will she ever unravel them all?
>
> [image: Front cover of "The Portal" (2019) by Kathryn Lasky.]

[This review](https://www.theprincessblog.org/2020/11/review-tangled-in-time-portal.html) states that the protagonist's name is Rose Ashley and that she's eleven years old.

> Eleven-year-old **Rose Ashley** was distraught when her mother passed away in a car accident. She is forced to move in with her grandmother in Indianapolis who appears to be experiencing symptoms of dementia. Things seem bad enough for Rose having to start a new school as an orphan when she encounters a trio of bullies. Not everyone at her new school is mean to her. She finds a small group of friends that include a wheelchair-bound boy named Myles, but she still feels like an outcast. All of that changes when she enters her grandmother's greenhouse one night, and something magical happens. Rose finds herself transported to the sixteenth century, where she is employed as a servant for Princess Elizabeth. Rose has some knowledge of history, but does not dare share her foresight with her new companions and instead does her best to blend in, She has an easier time when she becomes best friends with Fanny, another servant girl who is around the same age as her. With Fanny's help, Rose peels apart the layers of her late mother's past and her mysteriously absent father.